# Stored procedure, that Join two query, and write in another table

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that inserts data into a table, but doesn't insert the data if there is already the same entry in the destination table.

The stored procedure should be able to also update a cell of an already existing row.

I'm using a table, and a view, and make an inner join of them.

So far I was trying to use a `INSERT INTO`, `SELECT EXCEPT SELECT` method.

When I run it, it write into the table but doesn't care if there is already an entry...

```
INSERT INTO DestinationTable
    SELECT data 
    FROM TABLE 
    INNER JOIN V_VIEW ON TABLE.ID = V_VIEW_ID
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT data 
    FROM DestinationTable
```

Does anyone have an idea, why it doesn't work as intended ?

Also do you know a way to update the specific cell of the already existing row ?

The cell is a numeric data, it can be iterated.

Thank you guys, hope reading your answers soon!

Comment: Pick a Database, any database **but only one database, preferably the one you are actually using** These TAGS are designed to attract the correct audience for your question, so use the correct ones and help will be at hand

Comment: Why should I provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example for any SQL query question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Try looking at merge queries: https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-the-sql-merge-statement/

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll check into your link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think SQL MERGE statements can be of great use in your scenario

```
MERGE
    [ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] ]
    [ INTO ] <target_table> [ WITH ( <merge_hint> ) ] [ [ AS ] table_alias ]  
    USING <table_source> [ [ AS ] table_alias ]
    ON <merge_search_condition>  
    [ WHEN MATCHED [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]  
        THEN <merge_matched> ] [ ...n ]  
    [ WHEN NOT MATCHED [ BY TARGET ] [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]  
        THEN <merge_not_matched> ]  
    [ WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]  
        THEN <merge_matched> ] [ ...n ]  
    [ <output_clause> ]  
    [ OPTION ( <query_hint> [ ,...n ] ) ]
;
```

Official Microsoft Documentation: [SQL MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

For Examples and explanation: [Using MERGE in SQL Server to insert, update and delete at the same time](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/)

Comment: Hi Bilal, I validated your answer because it was the method I used.

Thank you for adding answering this old question.

Comment: thank you @Laernyl, you validating this answer will help other users facing same issue